# send calendar invite based on response

Tags: forms, office365-apps, power-automate

I want to create a form using Microsoft Forms to schedule some trainings and I wanted to use Flow to send out the person a calendar invite to the session they choose on the form.

what's the best way to go about doing this ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the answer on this post [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Using-Forms-to-create-an-Outlook-event-at-a-specific-time/td-p/110563) to start the flow and add another action to send an email with the link to the event created. You can also update the event with the person information using something like [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Create-O365-Calendar-Event-Invite-User-s/td-p/94666).

Images for reference:

1) Create the Flow part that gets the form inputs and convert into events.

[image]

2) Get the event created previously and update it with the email addresses from the people so they will receive an email with the invite.

[image]